# Down scaling sprite images in Phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have an issue with loading sprites in my game.

Thing is that it is a responsive game, and main issue I have is rendering in different resolutions.

My sprite is initially 900px as it should be that much on iPad for instance.

But when I scale that sprite with

```
sprite.scale.setTo(0.3, 0.3);
```

to have it fit on mobile phones, the image gets pixelated and cramped, and circle looks like anything but not circle.

So what is the correct way of down scaling images in Phaser?

Comment: what is the height of your sprite ?

Comment: Well image I'm loading image 700x700px and I need it scaled to 300x300 in some situations

Comment: It should be ok, you can try this `game.stage.smoothed = false;`

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? I've been having that same issue for a few days now and can't seem to figure it out

Comment: having the exact same issue. Did you find the solution? (I know its been a year now...)